# Problema umbral Listas Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

tengo un pequeño problema con las listas de sharepoint. Tengo una BD conectada a este sitio web, el problema es que mi lista de sharepoint tendrá aproximadamente unos 25.000 registros y sharepoint creo que tiene un umbral para las vistas de 5000.

El problema es que si filtro por determinados campos (Como uno que tengo FECHA), creo que al superar este umbral, hay fechas que en el filtro de la lista de sharepoint no visualizo! aunque si que están si voy cambiando de página o agrupando los días.

¿Sabéis de alguna solución?

Answer (score 0):

Si estas usando Sharepoint Online, no vas a tener forma de corregir este probema a menos que crees vistas en SharePoint, Si es una version en premisas en la administracion central e

Comment: Esto parece realmente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Con un poco mas de reputación, [vas a poder comentar en cualquier lado.](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor mira [answer]